# Is there a Python function to scrape different class names?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Here's the link: https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news?page=0

For every article in the news page, I am trying to scrape the name of the article + its short content +  link + date of release + the author's name.

I am facing some problems while the website has different classes name. For example:

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">...</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">...</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">...</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even">...</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd">...</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-6 views-row-even">...</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-7 views-row-odd">...</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-8 views-row-even">...</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-9 views-row-odd">...</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-10 views-row-even views-row-last">...</div>
```

Are there any ways to get the class other than making a long list of `if-else` statement?

Additional info: I am currently using BeautifulSoup4 and requests library.

Thank in advance for your time.

Edit: Here's my strategy, but I am quite sure that something inside the  `links` variable must be changed.

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
frame=[]
links=soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'group-left list-wrapper'})
print(len(links))
filename="mobi_health_news.csv"
f=open(filename,"w", encoding = 'utf-8')
headers="Title,Content,Date, Link, Author\n"
f.write(headers)

for j in links:
    Title = j.find("div",attrs={'class':'views-field views-field-title'}).text.strip()
    Link = "https://www.mobihealthnews.com"
    Link += j.find("div",attrs={'class':'views-field views-field-title'}).find('a')['href'].strip()
    Date = j.find('span',attrs={'class':'day_list'}).text.strip()
    Content = j.find('div', attrs={'class':'views-field views-field-body'}).text.strip()
    Author = j.find('span', attrs ={'class':'author_list'}).text.strip()
    frame.append((Title,Content,Date,Link,Author))        f.write(Title.replace(",","^")+","+Link+","+Author.replace(",","^")+","+Content.replace(",","^")+","+Date.replace(",","^")+"\n")
upperframe.extend(frame)
f.close()
```

Comment: can you please share your code? what you have tried

Comment: @Umair just edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to select by all class names found inside `class="..."`. Just pick one that's unique for each field.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news?page=0'    
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.select('.group-left .views-row'):
    title = row.select_one('.views-field-title').get_text(strip=True)
    content = row.select_one('.views-field-body').get_text(strip=True)
    link = 'https://www.mobihealthnews.com' + row.a['href']
    dt = row.select_one('.day_list').get_text(strip=True)
    author = row.select_one('.author_list').get_text(strip=True)

    print(title)
    print(link)
    print(dt,'by', author)
    print(content)
    print('-' * 120)
```

Prints:

```
Vitls scores 510(k) clearance for continual and remote vital signs monitoring device
https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news/vitls-scores-510k-clearance-continual-and-remote-vital-signs-monitoring-device
July 16, 2020 by Mallory Hackett
The information is stored and sent to hospital systems and the Vitls app, so healthcare providers can monitor the vital signs of their patients in real time, no matter where they are.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Walgreens, DoorDash partner on nonprescription delivery orders
https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news/walgreens-doordash-partner-non-prescription-delivery-orders
July 16, 2020 by Dave Muoio
Through the DoorDash app or website, consumers in certain cities can have over-the-counter medications and other products delivered to their homes.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Roche, Genentech ink real-world data deal with PicnicHealth
https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news/roche-genentech-ink-real-world-data-deal-picnichealth
July 16, 2020 by Laura Lovett
The original focus will be on multiple sclerosis but will extend to include Huntington's disease and hemophilia.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Teva Pharmaceuticals releases its prescription ProAir Digihaler in the US
https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news/teva-pharmaceuticals-releases-its-prescription-proair-digihaler-us
July 16, 2020 by Dave Muoio
The connected inhaler's launch will be followed by Teva's other Digihaler products before the end of the year.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Health equity focused startup Cityblock lands $53.5M in funding
https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news/health-equity-focused-startup-cityblock-lands-535m-funding
July 16, 2020 by Laura Lovett
This comes a year after its last $63 million funding round.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Roundup: Isle of Wight infections drop following launch of COVID-19 app, NHS Providers publish digital guide and more briefs
https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news/europe/roundup-isle-wight-infections-drop-following-launch-covid-19-app-nhs-providers-publish
July 16, 2020 by Sara Mageit
Also, a new study shows workers back restrictions on technology use since the rise of remote working.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mental health tech firm Meditopia scores $15 million in Series A round
https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news/europe/mental-health-tech-firm-meditopia-scores-15-million-series-round
July 16, 2020 by Tammy Lovell
The funds will be used to expand reach of its culturally-tailored mindfulness app.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oncoshot partners with MyDoc to offer second opinion advice for cancer patients
https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news/asia-pacific/oncoshot-partners-mydoc-offer-second-opinion-advice-cancer-patients
July 16, 2020 by Dean Koh
The service enables patients from the region to make informed decisions about cancer care, with the aim of expanding their treatment options and improving clinical outcomes.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tabula Rasa HealthCare launches MedWise to prevent adverse drug events
https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news/tabula-rasa-healthcare-launches-medwise-prevent-adverse-drug-events
July 15, 2020 by Mallory Hackett
With the service, pharmacists can compare multiple different medications and see how risky the combination is.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Care coordination, telehealth startups merge to support vulnerable senior populations
https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news/care-coordination-telehealth-startups-merge-support-vulnerable-senior-populations
July 15, 2020 by Dave Muoio
Arkos Health will weave together Curavi Health, CarePointe and U.S. Health Systems' various care platforms for payer and provider customers.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```